# How to implement token based pagination using cassandra python-driver?

Tags: python, orm, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-python-driver

Yes, iterate over `Query` is good thing, but i need paging results and send them with token to frontend.

Can i create token for previous page too?

How can i **get and use** `ResponseFuture._paging_state` in Models or Querysets.

I search something like [Manual paging (Node-JS)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/1.0/nodejs-driver/reference/paging.html?scroll=paging__manual-paging), but in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in `python driver v 3.7.0`
You can find usage example in tests files on [Github](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/commit/acd5f746d2f7586d94b8d96d2873aace1fdc5bf9)

```py
page_state = result_set.paging_state
result_set = self.session.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM test3rf.test", paging_state=page_state)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this isn't possible. At least I can't see a way for this to work by looking at the API and the documentation. There seems to be an open ticket ([PYTHON-200](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-200)) created by [Adam Holmberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20688/adam-holmberg) for this, which is still to be implemented.